# matplotlib plot numpy array and other things

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I am programming artificial neural networks at the moment and would like to plot e.g. the weights of the net which are stored as numpy arrays.
I have no experiance with matplotlib and the vast amount of possibilites confused me a bit.

Preferably I would like to update the plot every second or so and plot the numpy arrays as colored squares (greyscale for 0 to 1 interval weights, colored for other intervals like -1 to 1).

In addition to that I would also like to plot some output data in graphs (normally x/y integers).

How can I achieve this? Which things from matplotlib do I need?

Can someone provide a (easy) tutorial?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like matplotlib.animation module:

- http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html
- http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/
- http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations